# Unable to edit R function

Tags: r

I am trying to edit and save a function from an R package.  So far I have tried

```
my_edited_func <- edit(package_func)

my_edited_func <- package_func

fix(my_edited_func)
```

In both cases, a text editor opens up, where I can make changes, but when exiting with `:wq`, I get the following error:

> Error in .External2(C_edit, name, file, title, editor) :
>
> problem with running editor vi

I am using R 3.3.1 on OS X 10.11

Comment: What happens with `edit(package_func, editor = "vim")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixing the Editor

We're going to modify the `R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site` file to change default editors from `vi` to `vim`:

```
Rscript -e "R.home()"
```

You probably will get:

```
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
```

Then use:

```
vim /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Rprofile.site
```

Find:

```
options(editor="vi")
```

And switch it to:

```
options(editor="/usr/bin/vim")
```

### Misc notes

To edit a function simply do:

```
my_edited_func = edit(package_func)
```

From now on, call `my_edited_func()`.

In RStudio:

[image: sample edit in rstudio]

In Terminal:

[image: os terminal]

Though, for more control (and more effective saves) note the following...

### Free Function Info

You can grab the function source by just typing the function name:

e.g.

Declaring *trash*

```
trash = function(x = TRUE){
  !x
}
```

Calling:

```
trash
```

Output:

```
function(x = TRUE){
  !x
}
```

Grabbing the source here and making a slight change is then possible, e.g.:

```
trash2 = function(x = TRUE){
  x
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the changes I am making to the function are not taking effect.  Code stays the same.  The error message in my original post has something to do with this.

Comment: @cryptic0 try to modify the `R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site` using the steps above.